# Strange behavior in GCC: rvalue ref and lvalue ref are covariant return types

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, language-lawyer

I have this little piece of code:

```
struct Res { };

struct A {
    virtual Res &&foo();
};

struct B : A {
    Res &foo() override;
};
```

It compiles in GCC, but not in Clang: https://godbolt.org/z/65rffW .

According to the standard language quoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25813596/14756950), the lvalue reference is not a covariant return type for an rvalue reference.

Why doesn't GCC issue an error?

Comment: This is not such a complicated question to answer. Assuming that it is true that this is ill-formed, according to the C++ standard, this can only be either a compiler bug or a compiler extension. I am unaware of any gcc extension to this effect. Therefore, rules of logic conclude that this must be a compiler bug?

Comment: @A.Hristov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this

Comment: @A.Hristov it indicates that function is defined for an object type which is an rvalue, but is not needed here - the bug can be reproduced even with normal functions.

Comment: @SergeyA Removed teh rvalue ref to this in the code, it was a leftover from the real code that inspired the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was actually the subject of a standard defect report, a quite old one:

> 960. Covariant functions and lvalue/rvalue references
>      Section: 11.7.3  [class.virtual]     Status: CD2     Submitter: James Widman     Date: 1 September, 2009
>
> [Voted into WP at March, 2010 meeting.]
>
> 11.7.3 [class.virtual] paragraph 5 requires that covariant return types be either both pointers or both references, but it does not specify that references must be both lvalue references or both rvalue references. Presumably this is an oversight.

> Proposed resolution (February, 2010):
>
> Change 11.7.3 [class.virtual] paragraph 5 bullet 1 as follows:
>
> ...If a function D::f overrides a function B::f, the return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:
>
> - both are pointers to classes, **both are lvalue references to classes**, or **both are rvalue** references to classes<sup>106</sup>
>
> ...

From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#960

---

[The code is undoubtedly ill-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/zo4Efc), Clang and MSVC (at least) did address the issue whereas GCC did not.

I filed a bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99664

---

**Update:**

The bug was fixed, [test case here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/testsuite/g%2B%2B.dg/inherit/covariant23.C;h=b27be15ef4581951d880d1e655524bd9f74833cf;hb=d04b0c75794545f1f7a942764285e21eaf2915a1). Will be included in gcc 12.